# Set default route to devise login view for rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I am trying to configure my rails server so that `http://localhost:3000/` redirects to `http://localhost:3000/admin_users/sign_in` . This is the Devise login view for my AdminUser model.

I have tried the following in my routes file without success:

```
devise_for :admin_users
root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
```

The following presents the login form but fails when I try to login due to too many redirects:

```
devise_for :admin_users do
  root :to => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has nothing to do with routing

add this line to your applications controller

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

your application will ask for login before allowing user to visit any page

to skip authentication on any action just put this, just put this line in that action's controller

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:some_action]
```

you need to define the root route of your application so that after authentication a user can be redirected there eg:-

root to: 'users#index'

Comment: Thanks! This helped quite a bit. I had to create a controller for my AdminUser object so I could directly reference the actions. After that, the `before_filter` went to the sign in screen first and then redirected to where I needed it.